# What is the difference between using celery with and without multi

Tags: celery, celeryd, flask-celery

I noticed that there are two separate ways of running celery workers. You can start the workers with or without a `multi` command suffix:

```
celery multi start worker -A main.celery --concurrency=10
```

and

```
celery -A main.celery worker --concurrency=10
```

Is there a difference between the two, and is one of them recommended to use in production over another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

celery multi is more like a CLI to manage one or multiple workers and it is mostly for interactive use. In your example, if you start your worker with

`celery multi start worker -A main.celery --concurrency=10`

it actually starts your worker as a daemon. Once it is up and running, `celery multi` provides a range of commands to interact with your worker, for example to shut it down.

The 'standard' `celery worker` command starts the worker in the main thread:

`celery -A main.celery worker --concurrency=10`

In a production environment, I would use the standard (and not the multi) command. This separates the concern of actually running the worker from how/where to run your worker, think for example Docker or a Procfile.